# What is this 6-pin SMD from an ethernet switch?

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, integrated-circuit, surface-mount

Can anyone please identify this 6-pin SMD integrated circuit or what it does? I could not find it by the code written on it.

It is from an ethernet switch and I need to replace it. The switch accepts 5-12V input.

Note: I have another one of these boards and this IC is blown out on that board and the writing is unreadable. so I took a picture of this one. but since they both have the same symptoms I figured that I also should replace this one to see if it would work.
[image]

Comment: You state that you don't know what it does and that you need to replace it. How do you know it is faulty, if you don't know what it does?

Comment: Given the inductor, some sort of dc-dc

Comment: The pinout and general function matches e.g. TPS560430, LMR50410 or LMR51606, but not the marking.